# Powershell: remove element from object

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I’m trying to create a new Azure ARM deployment file scripted based on an existing ARM template.

Basically what I do is:

1. Export a JSON file for a VM
2. Convert the JSON file into an object in PShell
3. Make changes
4. Write a new JSON file

The problem I’m having now, is that the original JSON file has the `storageprofile.imagereference` enabled which needs to be deleted from the new JSON file.

I’ve tried to set the value of it (storageprofile.imagereference.id = $null) but ARM doesn’t like that and wants the whole storageprofile.imagereference entry removed.

So in my Pshell, my VMObjectFile is read like:

```
$VMObjectFile = (Get-Content $ImportFile | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

And the property I want to remove is set on:

```
$VMObjectFile.resources.properties.storageProfile.imageProfile
```

But how do I delete the whole tree? I already got rid of the “id” value and afterward can set the `$VMObjectFile.resources.properties.storageProfile.imageProfile` to `$null` (removing the id attribute),

But how do I completely remove imagereference from the subtree `$VMObjectFile.resources.properties.storageProfile`  as there are multiple entries that still exists under that path:

```
$VMObjectFile.resources.properties.storageProfile.osDisk
$VMObjectFile.resources.properties.storageProfile.dataDisk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing properties from a PowerShell object is not as obvious as one would think:

```
$data = '{"a":{"b":{"c":"something","d":"another thing"}}}' | ConvertFrom-Json

$data.a.b.PSObject.Properties.Remove("c")

$data | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Result:

```
{"a":{"b":{"d":"another thing"}}}
```

Comment: This saved my life thank you. I don't know why this information is so hard to come by.